# Android - Parse XML to JSON

Tags: android, json, xml, kotlin, simple-framework

My use case require me to fetch an XML formatted as below and need to map it into a JSON object:

```
<settings>
<client ip="......" lat="...." lon="...." isp="...." country="...."/>
<translation lang="xml"> </translation>
</settings>
```

I'm using Retrofit with Moshi as converter factory for the requests:

```
       Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).asLenient())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
```

I tried to create the response model with the help of SimpleXml **(com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.9.0)**, but so far no luck. I keep getting this error:

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $

Anyone might have an idea how to map this structure to Json? Thank you in advance!

Response models:

```
@Root(name = "settings", strict = false)
data class ConfigurationEntity(

    @field:Attribute(name = "client", required = false)
    @param:Attribute(name = "client", required = false)
    val client: ClientEntity?
)
```

```
@Root(name = "client")
data class ClientEntity(

    @field:Attribute(name = "ip", required = false)
    @param:Attribute(name = "ip", required = false)
    val ip: String?,

    @field:Attribute(name = "lat", required = false)
    @param:Attribute(name = "lat", required = false)
    val lat: String?,

    @field:Attribute(name = "lon", required = false)
    @param:Attribute(name = "lon", required = false)
    val lon: String?,

    @field:Attribute(name = "isp", required = false)
    @param:Attribute(name = "isp", required = false)
    val isp: String?,

    @field:Attribute(name = "country", required = false)
    @param:Attribute(name = "country", required = false)
    val country: String?
)
```

**Solution**

Retrofit builder:

```
       Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
```

Models:

```
@Root(name = "settings", strict = false)
class ConfigurationEntity {

    @field:Element(required = false)
    lateinit var client: ClientEntity
}
```

```
@Root(name = "client", strict = false)
class ClientEntity {

    @field:Attribute
    lateinit var ip: String

    @field:Attribute
    lateinit var lat: String

    @field:Attribute
    lateinit var lon: String

    @field:Attribute
    lateinit var isp: String

    @field:Attribute
    lateinit var country: String
}
```

Also this link may be helpful [Kotlin - parsing Xml response with list using SimpleXml](https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/95eccb8a-4ab5-4a67-acba-aef6df5dd772/y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add this converter factory to your Retrofit Builder -

```
Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
```

This allows Retrofit to interpret the XML that it is fetching to be converted to it's equivalent JSON Data Object.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Tried your suggestion and now I receive this error:
[Constructor not matched ].

In my opinion the issue is with this element because It contains multiple data within the tag:

<client ip="......" lat="...." lon="...." isp="...." country="...."/>

Comment: I'm glad it worked, and yes, try to match it exactly with the xml document that you have. For more info you can check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899858/android-retrofit-2-simple-xml-converter

Comment: Thank you dear, your references helped me with the solution! :)